# Mod rewrite rule doesn't work

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rule

I'm working with mod rewrite, but my code doesn't work. It worked for a time.
I have stripped the code.

*.htaccess*

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/$ index.php?test=$1
```

*PHP*

```
<?php
var_dump($_GET['test']);
?>
```

If I go to the `index.php` it displays `NULL`.

I don't understand why it doesn't work anymore. I hope you can help me.

P.s. I have tested whether the .htaccess file is loaded by making a login form with .htaccess.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get rid of the first slash:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?test=$1
```

And even then your rule will only apply when you enter a url that ends with a forward slash, so for example:

```
/index.php/
```

If you want it to work with any url, you need to remove the last slash as well:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?test=$1
```

**Edit:** To avoid rewriting of existing files and directories you need add some conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?test=$1
```

Comment: Thx, this worked! But I have an other question. In my index.php file I have a link to a stylesheet but that link is also rewrited. Even if I use an asbolute URL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the first slash in your rule

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?test=$1
```